# Reprojecting in GeoServer with custom transformation parameters

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geoserver, wms, autocad-map

I already set up a raster layer in GeoServer, store type is GeoTIFF with the EPSG:2462 and I'm trying to use it as WMS in AutoCAD and QGIS using the target EPSG:32634.

If I insert the same raster as a file based it is reprojected as it should be, but if I insert it as WMS through GeoServer I get it shifted several meters east.

I see from the QGIS coordinate system that it already has the transformation parameters correctly for that EPSG but I am not sure that when you insert a WMS raster layer it is reprojected by QGIS or through the GeoServer?

If it is reprojected by GeoServer how can I manage it or how can I use only the QGIS reprojection instead so everything to be OK as it is when you use a file based raster?

This is the CRS in QGIS: 
`+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=21 +k=1 +x_0=4500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=krass +towgs84=-44.183,-0.58,-38.489,2.3867,2.7072,-3.5196,-8.2703 +units=m +no_defs`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to check the definition of a CRS in GeoServer is to go to the `demos` menu and select `SRS List`:

In your case this will lead to [this page](http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.demo.SRSDescriptionPage?4&code=EPSG:2462):

```
PROJCS["Albanian 1987 / Gauss-Kruger zone 4", 
  GEOGCS["Albanian 1987", 
    DATUM["Albanian 1987", 
      SPHEROID["Krassowsky 1940", 6378245.0, 298.3, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7024"]], 
      TOWGS84[-44.183, -0.58, -38.489, -2.3867, 2.7072, -3.5196, -8.2703], 
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6191"]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4191"]], 
  PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","9807"]], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 21.0], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 4500000.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH], 
  AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","2462"]]
```

This seems to match QGis' definition exactly.

Answer (score 1):

The PROJ.4 definition of EPSG:2462 has been changed in the past.

The definition in GDAL 1.11 was:

```
 gdal-1-11>gdalsrsinfo epsg:2462

 PROJ.4 : '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=21 +k=1 +x_0=4500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=krass +units=m +no_defs '

 OGC WKT :
 PROJCS["Albanian 1987 / Gauss-Kruger zone 4",
  GEOGCS["Albanian 1987",
    DATUM["Albanian_1987",
        SPHEROID["Krassowsky 1940",6378245,298.3,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7024"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6191"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4191"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",21],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
PARAMETER["false_easting",4500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","2462"]]
```

and for GDAL 2.1.0 and later:

```
 gdal-2-1-0>gdalsrsinfo epsg:2462

 PROJ.4 : '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=21 +k=1 +x_0=4500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=krass+towgs84=-44.183,-0.58,-38.489,-2.3867,-2.7072,3.5196,-8.2703 +units=m +no_defs '


 OGC WKT :
 PROJCS["Albanian 1987 / Gauss-Kruger zone 4",
  GEOGCS["Albanian 1987",
    DATUM["Albanian_1987",
        SPHEROID["Krassowsky 1940",6378245,298.3,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7024"]],
        TOWGS84[-44.183,-0.58,-38.489,-2.3867,-2.7072,3.5196,-8.2703],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6191"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4191"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",21],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
PARAMETER["false_easting",4500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","2462"]]
```

The old GDAL misses the datum shift values. depending on the GDAL version your Geoserver uses, you will experience the datum shift between QGIS- and Geoserver- reprojected layers.